# AVPlayer / AVFoundation play specified HLS bandwidth and resolution

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, http-live-streaming

Is there any good solution of iOS AVPlayer to let user choose specified HLS video resolution / bandwidth?

So the question will be separated in to two

1. Get the resolution / bandwidth list in m3u8:
2. Specify the stream resolution and bandwidth

For 1. A workaround solution is to get `indicatedBitrate` of
    `AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent`
([Get bandwidth of stream from m3u stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689135/get-bandwidth-of-stream-from-m3u-stream))
The other possible solution is to download and parse m3u8, apart from the AVPlayer interface.

For 2. A workaround solution to change the default adaptive behavior of AVPlayer is to use `preferredPeakBitRate` or `preferredMaximumResolution`. But video quality might still get lower if network gets slower. ([Change HLS bandwidth manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039484/change-hls-bandwidth-manually))

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you need a m3u8 parser. e.g. https://github.com/alexsun/M3U8Paser

Comment: check out this https://github.com/alexsun/M3U8Paser/blob/b72ba607e1ab72cbc2aee839a2d24b9751d08f8a/Source/Master%20Playlist/M3U8ExtXStreamInf.h#L48